# How to use a custom validation access form in a component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I make a custom validator to check if an email exists in database before saving a new user, but it doesn't seem to work.

**My template**

```
<form class="forms-sample" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveUser(f.value)">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ngModel name="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" #email="ngModel" placeholder="Email" emailValidator>
  <div *ngIf="email?.errors.emailValidator">This email has been taken, please use another one.</div>
  .......................................................
  <button class="btn btn-md-12 btn-outline-primary btn-fw btn-icon-text clickable" [disabled]="f.invalid || userFile==null" type="submit">
</form>
```

**My validator**

```
import { NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, ValidatorFn, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from '../../services/users.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[emailValidator][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: EmailValidator,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class EmailValidator implements Validator {

  validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor(public usersService:UsersService) {
    this.validator = this.emailValidator("");
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
  }

  emailValidator(email:string): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: FormControl) => {
      this.usersService.checkEmailTaken(email)
        .subscribe((res)=>{
          let isValid = res;
          if (isValid==null) {
            return true;
          }
        });
      return {
        emailValidator: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    }
  }

}
```

**My service** returns the user if it exists or null if not.

```
checkEmailTaken(email: string) {
    if(this.jwtToken==null) this.authenticationService.loadToken();
    return this.http.get(this.host+"/checkEmailTaken?email="+email
      , {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwtToken})}
    );
}
```

The service works just fine, but i don't know why my custom validation doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You validator must be an asyc validator (you need call to a service), take a llok at https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/ or https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-custom-async-validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Service**

```
getUserByEmail(email:string){
    if(this.jwtToken==null) this.jwtToken = this.authenticationService.loadToken();
    return this.http.get(this.host+"/userByEmail?email="+email
      , {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwtToken})}
    );
}
```

**Validator**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncValidator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {UsersService} from '../../services/users.service';


export function uniqueUserEmailValidator(usersService: UsersService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return usersService.getUserByEmail(c.value)
      .map(data=> {
        return data ? { 'uniqueUserEmail': true } : null;
      });
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector : '[uniqueUserEmail][ngModel]',
  providers : [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting:UniqueUserEmailValidator, multi:true}]
})
export class UniqueUserEmailValidator implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  validate(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return uniqueUserEmailValidator(this.usersService)(c);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts** 
we must add the validator in our declarations so we can use it in our forms

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UniqueUserEmailValidator]
})
```

**Template**

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ngModel name="email" required uniqueUserEmail pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" #email="ngModel" placeholder="Email">
<div *ngIf="email?.errors.uniqueUserEmail">This email has been taken, please use a different one.</div>
```